# Can't execute a maven shell script with the prefix I gave it

Tags: maven

I'm trying to make a post deploy script for my project, which will test validity.

Now, the script is made, and I'm trying to make it run after all the sub modules.
The simplest way I could think of was simply to call the exec-maven-plugin with a specific prefix. I need a new prefix though, since I already have a different exec running on one of the sub modules.

so, I want to call it as: validate:exec

the relevant part of the xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                                    <executions>
                                            <execution>
                                                    <goals>
                                                            <goal>exec</goal>
                                                    </goals>
                                            </execution>
                                    </executions>
                                    <configuration>
                                            <executable>validate.py</executable>
                                            <goalPrefix>validate</goalPrefix>
                                            <arguments>
                                                    <argument>${deploy.host.fe</argument>
                                                    <argument>${deploy.port.fe}/argument>
                                            </arguments>
                                    </configuration>
                            </plugin>
```

This I put in my pluginsmanagement or plugins tag (spelled correctly), neither helped.
when I try to run:

mvn validate:exec

I get:
 No plugin found for prefix 'validate' in the current project and in the plugin groups...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try it the other way round. Exec should be in front. Just exec should do.